# use of system() function to open a filename given at runtime in C

Tags: c, system

I want to use the system() function to open an image whose name is given at runtime. For a fixed name it works, but, errors out if I pass another argument as it is not defined for two arguments.

I want something like the following, using any function that can achieve this.

```
system("gthumb <file1>");
```

where file1 stores the name of the file given at runtime.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post with the relevant part of your code so people can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Create a string with the complete command you want to execute, probably using `snprintf()`, and pass the resulting string to `system()`.

Comment: You [probably shouldn't use system][1]. can you just link to libgthumb and use their API (if they made that publicly accessible) instead of calling the binary?


  [1]: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `system()` call.

Anyway, what you have to do here, first is to compute the complete command line, using sprintf(). You have to do something like: `sprintf(string, "gthumb %s", file1);` and then, you call `system(string);`

Comment: `sprintf` is dangerous (can buffer overflow) and is becoming deprecated. `snprintf` is much better.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the functions of the snprintf familiy are not part of the C89 standard. So people using strict C89 will not be able to use them. Just for completeness' sake. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the command string, e.g. something like

```
  char cmdbuf[128];
  snprintf (cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "githumb %s", path);
  int res = system(cmdbuf);
```

but you should check the validity of `path` (or implement a quoting mechanism); if it contains `; rm -rf $HOME`  you'll be unhappy.