# c++ . when can a system call to move fail?

Tags: c++, system

Read some where that one should use `WEXITSTATUS` to check for return status of system calls . 
However I dont think that a call like `system("mv /a/b/c /a/b/d")` needs a check if it fails .

What are the conditions when this call may fail ?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: then don't code like this. See my answer. And accept one of the given answer if it fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities:

1. `/a/b/c` does not exist
2. `/a/b` does not exist
3. You have insufficient access to `/a/b/c`
4. You have insufficient access to `/a/b/d`
5. `/a/b/d` already exists
6. `/a/b/c` isn't moveable
7. There is no shell
8. `mv` does not exist
9. You have insufficient access to `mv`
10. You have no file system mounted
11. You have no storage available at all

And many, many more...

Comment: /a/b/c is in use by other program or locked

Answer (score 2):

`system("mv /a/b/c /a/b/d")` : very probably both `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/d` lie on the same mounted [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). I am guessing you have a [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) system, perhaps Linux.

Then it is much more simpler to use the [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) syscall (which is called by `/bin/mv` when relevant!) and directly code:

```
if (rename("/a/b/c", "/a/b/d")) {
   perror("rename failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and you would have thru [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) i.e. thru [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) the error code explaining why the rename failed. All the error conditions in [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) are relevant failure cases of `mv`, see also [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html)!

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

If (for some strange reason, e.g. `bind` mounts, symlinks, ...) `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/d`  don't lie in the same filesystem, you would get `errno == EXDEV` (and you might handle that case by a copy followed by an `unlink` of the source).

In general, using **`system("mv` ...`")` should be avoided**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161296/841108) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20835754/841108) explaining why (and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17440097/841108) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556732/841108)). And your user may have a different `mv` in his `PATH` (or some alias), so `mv` should at least be `/bin/mv` ... If `.` (or even worse `/tmp` !) is early in his `PATH` and has a symlink `mv` ➙ `/bin/rm` your user won't be happy!

BTW, you generally don't call `system` with a *compile-time constant* string starting with `mv`. That string is generally built. And if you don't quote correctly things (imagine one argument being `; rm -rf $HOME`) havoc can happen.
Also, [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) can fail e.g. because [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) failed (too many user processes, reaching the `RLIMIT_NPROC` limit of [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)...).